# UITableView - Callback for currently reordering cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

How can I find out if the user is currently reordering cells in a UITableView?

I need something like: willStartReorderingCells / didEndReorderingCells

Comment: Have been a while since I've used those myself, but look into `UITableViewDelegate` methods (can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html)). more precisely those two- `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:` or, if it fits your need better, this one- `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`

Comment: Probably `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` and `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys! I tried those.  tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath: and tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:  do not get called at all. tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath: does get called while moving a cell. But I was hoping for a startOfCellMovement and endOfCellMovement callback. None of these do that yet.